# .htaccess restrict subdomain by IP - Wordpress Multisite

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect traffic away from a subdomain install of Wordpress Multisite *unless* it's coming from a specific IP address/range, and without affecting the root domain traffic. Is this possible?

Conceptually, I've been thinking something like this:

```
# IF we're dealing with the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.example\.com [NC]

# AND the user is NOT from our allowed IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !111\.222\.333\.444

# THEN redirect them to the root domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

In other words, restrict access to the subdomain from all traffic that doesn't originate from a defined IP address. I've literally just learned regex and .htaccess for this, so apologies in advance for anything that's glaringly wrong.

The reason I'm not doing this with directory specific .htaccess is that I'm working with a subdomain install of Wordpress Multisite, so there are no directories. It's all in the URL.

Some possible complications that come from Wordpress itself:

1. Ideally these rules should be added in such a way that they aren't overwritten every time the permalink cache is refreshed in WP.
2. I'm not sure what `RewriteBase /` evaluates to, or how it's affecting URIs (if that's the correct acronym) in my file.

EDIT:

Per @Prix feedback, here is the complete .htaccess file I'm working with:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !111\.222\.333\.444
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is Wordpress' Multisite default rules, with my own additions included immediately after `RewriteBase /`. I incorporated @hjpotter92's suggestion.

The desired affect it to redirect *all* traffic from subdomain.example.com to example.com, *unless* it's coming from a specific IP address. This is for a client who's essentially using part of their Wordpress Multisite as a company extranet.

Comment: Use this rewriterule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=302]`

Comment: @Prix thanks for clarifying `RewriteBase`. I'm sorry that the post isn't more clear. The issue that I'm having with the above code is that it flat doesn't work. I'm novice enough at this that I assume I'm making fundamental errors, and am looking for feedback on how to do it right.

Comment: @hjpotter92 awesome! I'll check that out later tonight and let you know how it turns out. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The rewritten path should not have `\.` in it

Comment: I edited my question accordingly, and tested it as well. I didn't work however. The conditions don't seem to be triggering at all.

Comment: I'm using that IP exactly for testing, and it's not mine ;) The subdomain appears to be sharing the same document root to me. There is a type of WP Multisite that has directories, but that's not the one we're using unfortunately. When I check the file structure, there's only one. All distinction between sites seems to by in the database only. So basically what you both are saying, is that the syntax and everything looks correct and you would expect that to work?

Comment: I may have found a different type of solution entirely, using a PHP function. I suspect .htaccess might be more bullet proof, but never the less I need to move. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Prix Perfect! That's working. Thank you so much for your pointers.If you formalize the code block as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule looks fine yes, the only thing I would change is this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Into this

```
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [L,R=302]
```

As you don't want a 404 on the redirect aside from that given the subdomain share the same `DocumentRoot`, then yes, it should work as I have tested it myself.

And I hope at this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
```

You're not adding noise to it like `http://` or anything other than the qualified domain name, such as for example `intranet\.mydomainname\.com` no slash, no http, etc.

Comment: Thanks @prix, still working like a charm. I have a happy client.

Comment: We just activated SSL for the subdomain (the primary domain already had SSL), and now things are a little screwy. Even with the IP exceptions, we can only access the subdomain if we are logged into Wordpress. Any idea if the .htaccess needs to be tweaked for SSL/https?

Comment: @cskyleryoung it's a possibility, would have to look. If you post a new question with this issue I can try to assist you with. Also make sure to explain in what scenarios the SSL does not work and what happens for example it redirects you to non-https or just what.

Comment: I created a new questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901038/how-to-redirect-wordpress-multisite-subdomain-with-ip-exceptions  Thanks @prix!

Comment: @cskyleryoung will check it in a few ;)